# Duplicate symbol error in iOS build using Ionic Package Build and XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, linker, code-push

I have recently added the codepush plugin to my ionic framework app. I have been using the ionic cloud build facility, but i have the following error. So i tried it on my local xcode and had the same issue. I've tried remove the codepush plugin but that hasn't fixed it either. 
My app info

```
Ginils-MacBook-Pro:d2ub4IO ginil$ sudo ionic plugins ls
Password:
code-push 1.9.0-beta "CodePushAcquisition"
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.1 "ActionSheet"
cordova-plugin-code-push 1.9.2-beta "CodePush"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.4 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.0 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.0 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.3.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.5.1-dev "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.0 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-zip 3.1.0 "cordova-plugin-zip"
ionic-plugin-deploy 0.6.4 "IonicDeploy"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.0.3 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 3.2.1 "Launch Navigator"


Ginils-MacBook-Pro:d2ub4IO ginil$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.3 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
```

I'm not sure how to debug this further??

```
Ld /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass\ App.app/Mass\ App normal x86_64
    cd /Users/ginil/git/D2U/d2u/platforms/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk -L/Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass\ App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass\ App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Mass\ App.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass\ App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass\ App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Mass\ App_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a -lz -weak_framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreLocation -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreTelephony -framework MapKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass\ App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass\ App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Mass\ App_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass\ App.app/Mass\ App

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SSZipArchive._zip in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SSZipArchive-8D878CF05CB5F1A2.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SSZipArchive-E7FBEC607774F794.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SSZipArchive._path in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SSZipArchive-8D878CF05CB5F1A2.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SSZipArchive-E7FBEC607774F794.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SSZipArchive in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SSZipArchive-8D878CF05CB5F1A2.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SSZipArchive-E7FBEC607774F794.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SSZipArchive in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SSZipArchive-8D878CF05CB5F1A2.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SSZipArchive-E7FBEC607774F794.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SSZipArchive._filename in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SSZipArchive-8D878CF05CB5F1A2.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SSZipArchive-E7FBEC607774F794.o
duplicate symbol _zipCloseFileInZipRaw in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-7DF66A01D56638C.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-D074136927F32D65.o
duplicate symbol _zip_copyright in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-7DF66A01D56638C.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-D074136927F32D65.o
duplicate symbol _zipOpenNewFileInZip in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-7DF66A01D56638C.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-D074136927F32D65.o
duplicate symbol _zipWriteInFileInZip in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-7DF66A01D56638C.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-D074136927F32D65.o
duplicate symbol _zipCloseFileInZip in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-7DF66A01D56638C.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-D074136927F32D65.o
duplicate symbol _zipOpen in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-7DF66A01D56638C.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-D074136927F32D65.o
duplicate symbol _zipClose in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-7DF66A01D56638C.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-D074136927F32D65.o
duplicate symbol _zipOpenNewFileInZip4 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-7DF66A01D56638C.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-D074136927F32D65.o
duplicate symbol _zipOpen4 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-7DF66A01D56638C.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zip-D074136927F32D65.o
duplicate symbol _zipCloseFileInZipRaw64 in:
```

..........truncated

```
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGoToFilePos in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGetGlobalInfo in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGetCurrentFileInfo in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzOpen in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unztell in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzeof in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzClose in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGoToNextFile in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGoToFirstFile in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzOpenCurrentFile in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzCloseCurrentFile in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzReadCurrentFile in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzLocateFile in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzOpenCurrentFilePassword in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGetLocalExtrafield in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzSetOffset64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGetOffset64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGetCurrentFileZStreamPos64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGetFilePos64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGoToFilePos64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGetGlobalInfo64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGetCurrentFileInfo64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzOpen64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unztell64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzOpen2_64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzOpenCurrentFile3 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzOpen2 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGoToNextFile2 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzGoToFirstFile2 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _unzOpenCurrentFile2 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-277A9B0BABD36760.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/unzip-DF08DAD5EA21F0BC.o
duplicate symbol _fill_fopen_filefunc in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-B5A5F861828E8A92.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-3C6EA7F12EB3D15A.o
duplicate symbol _fill_fopen64_filefunc in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-B5A5F861828E8A92.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-3C6EA7F12EB3D15A.o
duplicate symbol _call_zopen64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-B5A5F861828E8A92.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-3C6EA7F12EB3D15A.o
duplicate symbol _call_ztell64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-B5A5F861828E8A92.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-3C6EA7F12EB3D15A.o
duplicate symbol _call_zopendisk64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-B5A5F861828E8A92.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-3C6EA7F12EB3D15A.o
duplicate symbol _call_zseek64 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-B5A5F861828E8A92.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-3C6EA7F12EB3D15A.o
duplicate symbol _fill_zlib_filefunc64_32_def_from_filefunc32 in:
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-B5A5F861828E8A92.o
    /Users/ginil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mass_App-etrjtratrwiyoocdnvpsltuiugql/Build/Intermediates/Mass App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mass App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ioapi-3C6EA7F12EB3D15A.o
ld: 68 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Conflicts exists between `ionic-plugin-deploy` and `cordova-plugin-zip`.

Steps:

1. Force remove cordova-plugin-zip

`cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-zip --force`

2. Remove ionic deploy

`cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-deploy --save`

3. Add cordove-plugin-zip

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-zip --save`

src:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/issues/190
- https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/issues/186

Comment: After a lot of searching this is the correct answer, I also had to do ionic cordova platform remove ios then add

Answer (score 0):

Please remove ionic console plugin for this issue

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-console
```